# How can I use the <src_datasource> parameter from gdal_rasterize?

Tags: gdal, ogr, gdal-rasterize

I'm using the following command to generate a TIFF file from a shapefile:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 -l layer_name input.shp output.tif
```

It works fine, but I'd like to use it with a GeoJSON file as input as well... On the [gdal_rasterize documention](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-arg-src_datasource) it says that I can use any OGR supported readable datasource, so it should accept GeoJSON files as input as well... I didn't understand how I should be using the `<src_datasource>` option. I've tried putting a GeoJSON file on the command directly as follows:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 -l layer_name input.geojson output.tif
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to create -2147483648x-2147483648 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
ERROR 1: Cannot create output.tif
```

I've also tried writing GeoJSON on the command:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 -GeoJSON -l layer_name input.geojson output.tif
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR 6: Too many command options 'output.tif'
```

What am I getting wrong? How can I use the OGR supported formats with `gdal_rasterize`?

Comment: You can only use one src_datasource, so you'd have to combine your shapefile and geojson file beforehand

Comment: @mikewatt Sorry, there was a typo on my question. I actually don't want to use two datasources with this command, I need it to convert a single GeoJSON to a TIFF file. The errors from my question happen when I use a single GeoJSON file as datasource... It works only when I use shapefiles...

Comment: Gotcha.  Your first command looks close, after `-l` you're missing the layer name.  [See here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#layer) for how to determine that for geojson, it may just be the filename without extension like you use for the shapefile example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original command options

`-l input input.shp`

the `input.shp` is the datasource and `input` is the layer of the datasource that will be used. If the datastore can contain many layers, or if the name of the layer is not known directly the desired layer can be selected with option `-l`. Shapefile can have only one layer and the name of the layer is the same than the name of the datastore and GDAL knows it. Therefore the `-l input`in your original command is unnecessary. The documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html is not quite clear about the fact that `-l` in not always needed.

GeoJSON can also have only one layer and GDAL knows that. You can use a command that is as simple as this:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 input.geojson output.tif
```

If you for some reason want to use the `-l` option with a GeoJSON file it is not as simple as with a shapefile because the layer name in GeoJSON can be something else than the file name. You can check what the layer name is with ogrinfo. In this example the name of the layer is `out`.

```
ogrinfo myPolygonizedImage.geojson
INFO: Open of `myPolygonizedImage.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
1: out (Polygon)
```